# Javascript - How to sort array of object by 3 different attributes type? (String, Integer, Boolean)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have array of object:

```
var a = [
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": [3], "size2": null },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 4, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
];
```

I want to sort it like this, Sort By `name` ascending, and then `no` ascending and then by size1 if it not null.

At first, I can sort it by `name` and `no`, but after that I don't know how to sort by `size1` or `size2`. It should sorted by size1 first if it is not null.
Here is my code to sort

```
function sortObject(arrayObjects){
    arrayObjects.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a.name=== b.name){
            return (a.no - b.no);
        } else if(a.name > b.name){
            return 1;
        } else if(a.name < b.name){
            return -1;
        }
    });
}
```

Expected result

```
var a = [
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 4, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": [3], "size2": null },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
]
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do when `size1` is `null`? And when do you use `size2`?

Comment: Yes, If size1 null, then I use size2. Each Object only has Size1 or Size2. I just need to sort it by size1 first, and then size2. It looks like grouping by Name and No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to compare `no` in your first `if`:

```
function sortObject(arrayObjects){
    arrayObjects.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a.name=== b.name) {
            if (a.no === b.no) {
                // Determines which size to use for comparison
                const aSize = a.size1 || a.size2;
                const bSize = b.size1 || b.size2;

                return (aSize[0] - bSize[0]);
            }
            return (a.no - b.no);
        } else if (a.name > b.name) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a.name < b.name) {
            return -1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What about `null` checks?

Comment: What is expected with `null`?

Comment: `size1` can be `null`. If you execute `null - [3]` - what result do you get in this case?

Comment: I just updated my answer with the details provided in the comments of the question.

Comment: Note that those "size" properties look like they're arrays, and not plain numbers.

Comment: @Telokis yes, that looks better now

Comment: Tru, I edited the answer and removed the lodash part

Comment: This is it, i try it and it amazingly sort my objects. Thanks @Telokis

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified version of [`orderBy`](https://30secondsofcode.org/object#orderby) from 30 seconds of code (a project/website that I maintain), which also checks for `null` and orders accordingly:

```js
var a = [
{"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": [3], "size2": null },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 4, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
];

const orderBy = (arr, props, orders) =>
  [...arr].sort((a, b) =>
    props.reduce((acc, prop, i) => {
      if (acc === 0) {
        const [p1, p2] = orders && orders[i] === 'desc' ? [b[prop], a[prop]] : [a[prop], b[prop]];
        acc = p1 === null ? 1 : p2 === null ? -1 : p1 > p2 ? 1 : p1 < p2 ? -1 : 0;
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0)
  );
  
 var aSorted = orderBy(a, ['name', 'no', 'size1', 'size2'], ['asc', 'asc', 'asc', 'asc']);
 
 console.log(aSorted);
```

How `orderBy` works:

*Uses `Array.sort()`, `Array.reduce()` on the `props` array with a default value of `0`, use array destructuring to swap the properties position depending on the order passed. If no `orders` array is passed it sort by `'asc'` by default.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

1. For string comparison [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
2. For number/Array length subtraction

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [
{"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": [3], "size2": null },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 4, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
{"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
{"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let check = a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  if (check == 0) {
    check = a.no - b.no;
    if (check == 0) {
      check = (b.size1 || []).length - (a.size1 || []).length;
    }
  }
  return check;
});

console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var a = [
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 4, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "AAA", "no": 5, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": [2], "size2": null },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 1, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": [3], "size2": null },
  {"name": "BBB", "no": 2, "size1": null, "size2": [1] },
]

a.sort(function(a, b){
  return  a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
          a.no - b.no ||
          (b.size1 === null) - (a.size1 === null) ||
          (b.size2 === null) - (a.size2 === null)
});

console.log(a)
```